# Python: Writing/appending to a file inside a thread class error

Tags: python, multithreading, file, io

Im trying to periodcally write some measurements into a txt file. (some sorta logging).

To periodically run a function, there is a RepeatTimer class. And to run the function of updating the file I have a VTlog() function as below.

```
class RepeatTimer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, iterations=0, args=[], kwargs={}):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.iterations = iterations
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.finished = Event()

    def run(self):
        count = 0
        while not self.finished.isSet() and (self.iterations <= 0 or count < self.iterations):
            self.finished.wait(self.interval)
            if not self.finished.isSet():
                self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
                count += 1

    def cancel(self):
        self.finished.set() 



def LogVT():
    tgt_picks = [t1,t2] #modify here for selective targets
    for tgt in tgt_picks:
        tt = tgt
        file = ('c:/vtlogs_%s.txt' % str(tt.target_name))
        x = str(tt.voltage('v_1p05_gfx_uncore')) + ', ' + str(tt.voltage('v_1p5_sm')) + ', ' + str(tt.temperature('pch_temp'))
        q = time.strftime('%m/%d/%y, %H:%M:%S')
        filehandle = open(file, 'a')
        filehandle.write('\n' + q + ', ' + x)
        filehandle.close()
        time.sleep(3)


logtimer = RepeatTimer(60.0, LogVT)
logtimer.start()
```

the 'x' and 'q' works separetely when queried offline. t1 & t2 are some system attached with voltage & temp measurement device. api is already initiated.

My issue is, Im getting this at runtime:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 750, in emit
    self.stream.write(fs % msg)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Any explanation why??

Comment: have you got many RepeatTimer threads running? if yes, both threads are trying to write to the file, so it can happen that a thread tries to write to the file while it was just closed by another thread, and you should use a Lock to prevent concurent accesses to that file.

Comment: I have two RepeatTimer threads running. One constantly pings a target(remote server) for alive check but doesnt accesses any files. The second does the logging as above. I would google Lock method and investigate. Thanks.

Comment: Add: in fact the file has some loggings written to it as expected from the script. But still, the error surfaces on the interpreter. Perhaps has something to do with the for loop.

Comment: Can you try running it with `filehandle = open(file, 'a', 0)` ?

Comment: @ypercube: still the same.. does [code] filehandle = open(file, 'a', 0) [code] work if the file does not exists in the 1st place? do i need to create a txt file 1st before appending or will it create 1?

Comment: No, opening the file for appending or writing will create the file if necessary.

Comment: The threads are probably the cause of this, as Mat mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if `open()` was done correctly and a file handle was in fact returned or an error occured before making any calls to `write()` or `close()` for that file handle.

------------CORRECTION-----------

You should check if `open()` was done correctly but not for the reson I mentioned above. `open()` will raise `IOError` if it can't open the file, so this has nothing to do with your problem.

As Mat suggested, the threads are probably the cause of this. try something like:

```
...

    def run(self):
        count = 0
        # creating a lock
        lock = Lock()
        while not self.finished.isSet() and (self.iterations <= 0 or count < self.iterations):
            self.finished.wait(self.interval)
            if not self.finished.isSet():
                # call function with lock
                self.function(lock, *self.args, **self.kwargs)
                count += 1

...

def LogVT(lock):
    tgt_picks = [t1,t2] #modify here for selective targets
    for tgt in tgt_picks:
        tt = tgt
        file = ('c:/vtlogs_%s.txt' % str(tt.target_name))
        x = str(tt.voltage('v_1p05_gfx_uncore')) + ', ' + str(tt.voltage('v_1p5_sm')) + ', ' + str(tt.temperature('pch_temp'))
        q = time.strftime('%m/%d/%y, %H:%M:%S')
        # lock while doing file operations
        lock.acquire()
        filehandle = open(file, 'a')
        filehandle.write('\n' + q + ', ' + x)
        filehandle.close()
        # unlock
        lock.release()
        time.sleep(3)

...
```

Comment: well.. the string values have been correctly appended in the vtlog_target1.txt. but the interpretor gives that error.